# aem 6.1 extend user properties

Tags: java, adobe, aem, sling

[Printscreen additional fields useradmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW3so.png)

How can I add some new User Properties to the CQ Users?

I found an solution but it don't work --> http://experience-aem.blogspot.ch/2014/01/aem-cq-56-extend-useradmin-add-new-user.html

I tried to manipulate in CRX the UserProperties.js with new Properties, I see them in useradmin but if I try to add the new propertie in Java Code (not via useradmin) I can save it without error, but the value is empty in useradmin.
And if I try to add some value via useradmin for the new propertie, all user gets the same value.

How can I add new User Properties, that I can set the Value via Java code like the standard properties.

```
user = userManager.createUser(username, password);
                ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
                emailValue = valueFactory.createValue(email);
                givennameValue = valueFactory.createValue(givenname);
                nameValue = valueFactory.createValue(name);

                //User class just accepts Value Object
                user.setProperty("profile/" + UserProperties.EMAIL, emailValue);
                user.setProperty("profile/" + UserProperties.FAMILY_NAME, nameValue);
                user.setProperty("profile/" + UserProperties.GIVEN_NAME, givennameValue);
```

Comment: you need admin userManager to save the user on publisher ||||||||| Session adminSession = repositroy.loginAdministrative(null);
            
            UserManager usermanager = AccessControlUtil.getUserManager(adminSession);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an solution.
Go to crx /libs/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/security/UserProperties.js

1. add the fields you need in the items array of the user (Caution - there are items for user and items for groups in the same place)
2. in the loadRecord method of your JS, you have to add each new field to the "record" object

   ```
          "items":[{

               "xtype":"textfield",
               "fieldLabel":CQ.I18n.getMessage("Mail"),
               "anchor":"100%",
               "vtype":"email",
               "msgTarget":"under",
               "name":"email"
           },{
               "xtype":"textfield",
               "fieldLabel":CQ.I18n.getMessage("My Field"),
               "anchor":"100%",
               "msgTarget":"under",
               "name":"myfield"
           },{
               "xtype":"textarea",
               "fieldLabel":CQ.I18n.getMessage("About"),
               "anchor":"100% -155",
               "name":"aboutMe"


       }],


   loadRecord: function(rec) {
   this.enableUserSaveButton(false);
   this.enableGroupSaveButton(false);

   var type = rec.get("type");
   if (type=="user") {
       this.activeForm = this.userForm;
       this.hiddenForm = this.groupForm;
       if (rec.id==CQ.security.UserProperties.ADMIN_ID) {
           this.pwdButtons.each(function(bt) {bt.hide(); return true;} )
       } else {

           this.pwdButtons.each(function(bt) {bt.show(); return true;} )
       }

   } else {
       this.activeForm = this.groupForm;
       this.hiddenForm = this.userForm;
   }
   //is loading additional property from json and show it in formular
   rec.data["myfield"] = rec.json["myfield"];

   this.activeForm.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
   ```

In the java code you can then add the new properties via the "user" object to the new properties. Note that the properties are put into the subfolder "profile".

```
user.setProperty("profile/" +  "myfield", myFieldValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the second approach, posted by "pedro" in the link you've posted?
It probably has to do with pushing the new field to the record:
http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2014/01/aem-cq-56-extend-useradmin-add-new-user.html?showComment=1390804750445#c2823498719990547675

Answer (score 0):

i hope this may helps you the file exist on  http://[host name]:[port]/crx/de/index.jsp#/libs/cq/security/widgets/source/widgets/security/UserProperties.js

and you will have two major properties the first one is for the user `this.userForm` the other one is `this.groupForm` for groups.

Comment: You are sharing a `localhost` URL, quite useless.